# Why it is not possible to build binary semaphore with if statement inside in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

I have a small question that makes me a little confused.

This is my code:

```
public synchronized void P() {
    while(!_state) {
        this.wait();
    }
    _state = false;
}
```

This method is responsible for taking semaphore.
Why it is not possible to build binary semaphore with `if` statement instead of `while` loop?

The oracle docs says:

> First, it is not possible for two invocations of synchronized methods on the same object to interleave. When one thread is executing a synchronized method for an object, all other threads that invoke synchronized methods for the same object block (suspend execution) until the first thread is 
>   done with the object.

So exactly only one thread should be inside the P() method -> so only one thread should be blocked on wait() method. Rest of threads should be blocked on P() method level. But when I am replacing `while()` for `if()` it does not work properly

Comment: wait does not bloc, execution. It parks current thread. So when you wait another thread will be able to enter and wait as well.

Comment: Besides do you `notify` somewhere? if not, then it is not working like you described even with `while` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why it is not possible to build binary semaphore with `if` statement instead of `while` loop?

For a deep answer, you should work through Oracle's [Guarded Blocks tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html).

The shorter answer is, there's a couple of reasons why `_state` could be `false` when the `wait()` call returns:

1. Multiple consumers: It generally is safer to wake sleepers with `notifyAll()` instead of `notify()`, and if you write a program in which two or more threads could call the `P()` function, you probably only want *one* of them to be allowed to proceed when some other thread calls the `V()` function. So, if they all "wake up", you'll want just one to set `_state=false;` and you'll want the others to go back to sleep.
2. The same object is getting `notifyAll()` calls for more than one reason.  It's not good practice, but it happens, especially in projects where many developers contribute to the code. In that case, you don't wan the `P()` call to return if the object was notified for the wrong reason. You want it to go back and continue waiting.
3. The documentation for `o.wait()` says that it is allowed to return even when object `o` has not been notified at all. This is known as "spurious wakeup." It happens rarely, and only in some operating systems, but they allow it because it enables a more efficient implementation of `wait()` and `notify()`.

Answer (score 0):

`synchronized` method is equivalent to `synchronized(this)` block.

Only 1 thread is allowed to enter synchronized block. By entering it, thread aquires lock. When you `wait` inside sync block, you release the lock (object monitor) and park current thread. At this moment, another thread is allowed  to enter that block. Execution will continue when other thread will invoke `notify` or `notifyAll` on the same object that `wait` was invoked. Notified thread will "exit wait state" when given sync block's lock will be released.

To sum up - wait does not work like you expect, it does not block execution, only puts waiting thread to sleep, allowing other threads to aquire sync lock.

So you cannot do what you want to achieve, because `wait` works differently then you expect. What you want to use here, is `ReentrantLock`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html

Comment: Wait blocks the execution of the thread that executed the wait function.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I understand much more than before but I still have one question. What will happen when two or more threads will fall asleep on wait method and then I invoke notify method? Which one will wake up because only one can be during execution of synchronized method? I have second method V() that change _state on true and invoke notify method

Comment: `notifyAll` will wake both threads, and they will exit one by one (as "only 1 thread in block alowed" rule still applies). Order is undetermined. `notify` will wake one of those threads - undetermined which one. .